# Split strings using Group Separator (GS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, split, delimiter

How would I use [Python's split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) on a text file using ASCII decimal 29 [Group Separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators) for separator?

I have text files that Notepad++ displays GS icons between chunks of text which I believe are Group Separators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[zwer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7553525/zwer) has provided a solution in a comment:

You can easily define your ASCII char from your code: `.split(chr(29))`